# numbers only push to one index in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, indexing

I'm am trying to push numbers in an array from a variable. 
each time a checkbox is clicked its bring back a number which I then want to be pushed into an array. but every time, all numbers are concatenated in the first cell of the array, where I need to hold these numbers separately.

can anyone help?

```
$('#tbldata tr:has(td)').find('.checkboxes').click(function() { 
    var stuff = [] ;
    var Checked = $(this).prop("checked");
    var sep = 0;
    //var val =   $('#tbldata tr:has(td)').find('.checkboxes').find('td:eq(2)').closest("#reqnum").val();
    if(checked = 'checked')
        alert("clicked");
    sep+ 1;

    var selectedRows = JSON.parse("["+ ($('table._tm' ).find('tbody')// select table body and
    .has( 'input[type=checkbox]:checked' )
    .find( 'td' )
    .find( '.reqnum' )).text() + "]");// checked checkbox element

    stuff.push(selectedRows);
    console.log(stuff);

    $('#buttonDone').click(function() {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "isdone.php",
            data: {reqnum : reqnum},
            success: function(data)
            {
                alert(data);
                alert("success!");
                //alert("con7: " + con7 + "rowid" + rowid);
            }
        });
        console.log("hello");
    });
});
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jquery's `text()` method concatenates the text content of every elements. Here is a solution

Same goes for `var stuff = [];`.

```
$('#tbldata tr:has(td)').find('.checkboxes').click(function() {
  var stuff = $('table._tm' )
    .find('tbody')
    .has('input[type=checkbox]:checked')
    .find('td')
    .find('.reqnum'))
    // Uses map to apply text on each element separately.
    .map(function(){
      return $(this).text();
    })
    // Transform the jquery object to a JS array.
    .toArray();
  console.log(stuff);
});
```

I kept your selector as is even though it looks like it could be simpler.

See snippet below for a working example.

```js
$('#container input[type="checkbox"]').click(function(){
  var checkedLabels = $('#container li')
    .has('input[type=checkbox]:checked')
    .find('label')
    .map(function(){
      return $(this).text();
    }).toArray();
  console.log(checkedLabels);
});
```

```css
#container {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="container">
  <li><input type="checkbox" id="c1"/> <label for="c1">check 1</label></li>
  <li><input type="checkbox" id="c2"/> <label for="c2">check 2</label></li>
  <li><input type="checkbox" id="c3"/> <label for="c3">check 3</label></li>
  <li><input type="checkbox" id="c4"/> <label for="c4">check 4</label></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: sorry please igonre sep i was going to use it for a for loop. but it didnt work how i wanted it

Comment: Same goes for `stuff`. If it is inside your `click` handler, it will be a different array every time. Initialize it outside. That's why it does no work.

Comment: it work but the 2nd index now second index has both values concat together

Comment: (3) [Array(1), Array(1), Array(1)]0: [20893]1: [2089320885]2: [208932088520884]0: 208932088520884length: 1__proto__: Array(0)length: 3__proto__: Array(0)

Comment: see it keeps layering.

Comment: I do not understand what you copied. But are you sure you are not mistaken the 2nd cell of your array for the 2nd log in your console? The last version of your array should be displayed in the last log.

Comment: Oh. Or it might just be the code of `selectedRows` does not do what you think it does. I am not sure what you are trying to do on this line, but I believe it is going to concatenate some values of every checked checkboxes, not only the last one.

Comment: basically what i send is my console in google chrome

Comment: and the numbers are size of the first array. so what happening is when its does the second array its getting the first numberand the secound number and pushes both these numbers into second index and so on.

Comment: OK, what would you want there? Are you just trying to get an array of the selected cells?

Comment: basically the value for selectedRows is coming from a table where checkboxs are on every row.

Comment: Try this: `console.log($('table._tm' ).find('tbody').has( 'input[type=checkbox]:checked' ).find( 'td' ).find( '.reqnum' )).text())`, is this what you are looknig for?

Comment: so where the user clicks a checkbox that number is then feed back. im then trying to push into an array then throw the array back php so i can run query on all of them.

Comment: I can get the number showing up there is  no problem with that I just need the number to be in an array in separate index's

Comment: OK. Try this `$('table._tm' ).find('tbody').has( 'input[type=checkbox]:checked' ).find( 'td' ).find( '.reqnum' )).toArray().map(e => e.innerHTML)`

Comment: where should i but as a definition for selectedRows?